# Could any one please help me to get difference between sending data as Request Body and Request Header?

Tags: java

Please give me clear definition with a sample code, or suggest the specified books for that.

Thank You,

Bhanu Prakash Achary

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the difference between GET and POST method of HTTP.

This link may be helpful:
[Methods GET and POST in HTML forms](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you're talking about HTTP Request Headers*

HTTP Request Headers are pretty much defined (i.e. [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) has set of header field you can use for HTTP Request Headers) headers. If you add your own, other applications that read HTTP request headers won't understand it, if it follows RFC 2616 strictly.

As for Request Body, also known as *Message Body*

> The message-body (if any) of an HTTP
>   message is used to carry the
>   entity-body associated with the
>   request or response. The message-body
>   differs from the entity-body only when
>   a transfer-coding has been applied, as
>   indicated by the Transfer-Encoding
>   header field (section 14.41).

Basically, every request/response can carry a message body. That message can be a text, parameters, image, etc. It can contain an entity body combined with a message body (which is encoded).

More info, visit [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html).